# PHP understanding memory limit error

Tags: php, memory

I'm getting this error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4194304 bytes)
```

How come he tried to allocate `4194304` (which is smaller than the limit he specifies `134217728`) and is exhausted?

Comment: What does your code that produced this error look like?

Comment: 4194304 is additional bytes that php was trying to allocate, but memory was full at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP tried to allocate an extra of **`4194304`** bytes (after your code reached the upper limit of 134217728) , but your code exhausted that too.)

**`134217728`** was the limit which your code exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

When working with resource heavy operations there are a couple of things to consider and multiple steps to prevent memory exhaustion.

- How much data do we cache at any given time?
- How many iterations will there be?
- How do I keep the memory usage down to a minimum?
- Do I have to keep all data in memory during the entire execution?
- ...

You are exhausting your memory most likely due to not flushing or destroying old data from the current execution. That is why PHP peaks it's allowed allocation of system memory.