# PHP memory_limit fatal error in array_search function

Tags: php, memory, memory-leaks, fatal-error

I have this code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE & ~E_NOTICE);
$uarray = json_decode($_POST['array']);

$uac = $uarray;
$res = $uarray;

function request_callback($response, $info, $request) {
global $uac;
global $res;
$index = array_search($request->{'url'}, $uac);
$uac[$index] = " ";
$rspnc = json_decode($response);
$res[$index] = $rspnc;
}

require("RollingCurl.php");

$rc = new RollingCurl("request_callback");
$rc->options = array(CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);
$rc->window_size = 5;
foreach ($uarray as $url) {
$request = new RollingCurlRequest($url);
$rc->add($request);
}
$rc->execute();

for($i = 0; $i <= count($res); $i++)
{
for ($j = 0; $j <= 1; $j++) {
echo $res[$i]->{'name'};
echo "/";
echo $res[$i]->{'quality'};
echo "/";
echo $res[$i]->{'buy_offers'}[$j]->{'o_price'};
echo "/";
echo $res[$i]->{'buy_offers'}[$j]->{'c'};
echo "/";
echo $res[$i]->{'buy_offers'}[$j]->{'my_count'};
echo "/";
echo $res[$i]->{'classid'}. "_"  .$res[$i]->{'instanceid'};
echo "<br>";
}
echo "<p><p><p>";
}
?>
```

And im getting memory limit error in this string:

```
$index = array_search($request->{'url'}, $uac);
```

Array $uarray contains 10000 urls. I have already changed memory_limit value in php.in to -1. phpinfo() displaying memory_limit value as -1. So I have suppose that error occured because of 32bit PHP and Apache. I have windows 64bit with 16GB ram. So problem in the code. Help me rewrite this code especially array_search function in the way that original array will be sliced and merged back or so. Sorry for my language.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942839/php-understanding-memory-limit-error  can you please check this.. may be this will help

Comment: You can also try http://www.anindya.com/ At first I would give a try the posted link from Tejas.

Answer (score 0):

At this case is better to send data as body and read it from `php://input` by short portions. If every row will be separated by `\n` (for example), you may read line by line. So, you can avoid to load all data from stream to array `$uarray`.

For example, you sand request with next body:

```
[
    {"name":"name1","quality":"1"},
    {"name":"name2","quality":"2"}
]
```

You can read it line by line:

```
$handle = fopen('php://input', 'r');
do {
    $str = fgets($handle);
    $data = json_decode($str);
    if ($data) {
        // do what you need
        echo $data->name . PHP_EOL;
        echo $data->quality . PHP_EOL;
    }
} while ($str);
```

Comment: sorry but i don't fully undrestand what you mean. can u paste little code or something ?